# Google External Login Fails with no Error Message - But Facebook Works

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-5, oauth-2.0, asp.net-identity

I'm using MVC External Authentication providers for both Google and Facebook.  I have easily gotten both working many times before.

For some reason today, on a brand new project (File | New Project | MVC 5 Web App) in VS 2015 - it is the completely default project.  The only thing I have done is provide the App Keys and Secrets for both Google and facebook.

Facebook works all the way through, calls back - asks me to register as a new user - and then logs me in as that user.

Google gets all the way to the point where it WOULD call back to the OAuth Callback url - but that never happens, and instead I'm just redirected back to the login page with no further explanation.  There are no errors, no messages are logged anywhere that I can find, and no exceptions are thrown.

If instead, I register as a password user, and then try to link the account - I am able to do so without any trouble with facebook.  However, again, with the Google external provider, it gets to the point where the OAuth callback uri WOULD Be triggered, but instead, it just take me back to the "/ManageLogins" page with the generic error "An Error has Occurred".

I have enabled every type of exception that I could possible trap - but I get absolutely no feedback from the process except that it didn't work.  And since I literally have not yet had a chance to write a single line of code, I'm not sure what else to try.

I have spent almost 6 hours now trying to get this basic identity management part of the project completed - and while it usually only takes 10-15 minutes, I am completely blocked.  And since there is so little feedback from the code itself, I'm hoping that someone has run into this before and might be able to help.

Thanks.

Other Things I've tried:
1) it was original http - I thought that might be the problem, so I got an ssl certificate - and have converted it to https.  Same problem.

2) I have cleared my cookies, tried incognito, tried in many browsers - always the same result.

3) Original it was a new project in a larger solution - so I have now just created a new web project in it's own solution. Same problem.

4) I have switched to 2 different domains, and tried it from localhost of course.

Running out fo things to try....

EJ

Comment: You've verified that you have the correct setup in the Google API console? I believe they have made changes recently and it might require revisiting your registered apps

Comment: I have checked, and re-checked, but I will go back and make sure I didn't miss anything.  The fact that it works on facebook I only verified right before posting this - so clearly it is something specific to Google.  Thanks for the suggestion.  The fact that it is a File | New Project is what's most frustrating.  I have not done anything other than enable the 2 authentication methods.  :(

Comment: What is your callback url?

Comment: https://domain.com/signin-google

with many varions including no https, and various local host versions. 

http://localhost:12345/signin-google

And there are no complaints about the callback.  It just doesn't actually happen.

Comment: @eejai42 have you got the solution for this problem? I'm on the same situation. Thanks.

Comment: Sorry, I don't.  It's incredibly frustrating.  For now, I'm just using Facebook, but that's obviously not a viable long term solution.  If you figure it out, I'd appreciate a heads up.

Answer (score 0):

I know its an old thread, but I ran into the exact same issue. You have to make sure that Google+ API is enabled in Google Developers Console.